# Как запустить функцию в python на постоянное выполнение при обновление информации

Tags: python, функции, циклы

У меня есть код, который сначала вытягивает у пользователя телеграм бота изображение, потом прогоняет его через pytesseract и на выходе (на данный момент) печатает результат в консоли, но при попытке скинуть второе изображение, файл меняется, но функция не выводит результат со второй картинки, подскажите, как правильно сделать этот цикл

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("id")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo(message):
     fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
     file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
     downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
     with open("image.jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
         new_file.write(downloaded_file)


img = Image.open("image.jpg")
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
a = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
string = a
operations = ['+', '-', '/' ,'*']
operation = ''
counter = 0
one_number = list()
two_number = list()

l = [i for i in string] 

for elem in l: 
    if elem in operations:   
        operation = elem
        counter += 1
    elif elem.isdigit() and operation == '':
        one_number.append(elem)
    elif elem.isdigit() and operation != '':
        two_number.append(elem)

if counter == 1 and one_number != [] and two_number != []:     # Проверка, что бы был один мат оператор, и по обе стороны от него были цифры
    if operation == '+':
        result = int(''.join(one_number)) + int(''.join(two_number))
    if operation == '-':
        result = int(''.join(one_number)) - int(''.join(two_number))
    if operation == '/':
        result = int(''.join(one_number)) / int(''.join(two_number))
    if operation == '*':
        result = int(''.join(one_number)) * int(''.join(two_number))
    print(result)
else:
        print('Не расспознано')
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что проблема в том, что код по преобразовании картинки находится вне функции, поэтому программа до нее не доходит.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/806055)

Answer (score 0):

сдвинуть на 4 пробела перобразование image,

```
    a = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    string = a
```

заменить на

```
    string = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

и подсказывали что преобразование без списков лучше. работать со строкой